# FLTK: XLib error with X window initialization with multiple Fl_Windows

Tags: c++, x11, xlib, fltk

Per design requirements, I am developing a GUI in FLTK that must have a main (parent) window, a child window, and an X Window that is the child of the child window. This is in Ubuntu 16.04.

Running my original project with this setup produces the XLib error `BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) (Details: serial 7 error_code 3 request_code 1 minor_code 0)`.

I have the following test program with only the features relevant to the error that reproduces a similar error:

```
#include <FL/Fl.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Window.H>
#include <FL/Fl_Button.H>
#include <FL/x.H>

#include <iostream>

class ChildWindow : public Fl_Window {
public:
    ChildWindow() : Fl_Window(100, 100, 300, 200, "Child"){
        this->end();
        this->show();

        Display * dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

        std::cout << "Child XID: " << (void *)fl_xid(this) << '\n';
        std::cout << "XWindow XID: " << dis << '\n';

        Window win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dis, fl_xid(this),
            5, 5, 100, 100, 0, 0, 0);
        XMapRaised(dis, win);
        XSync(dis, false);
    }
};

class ParentWindow : public Fl_Window {
public:
    static ChildWindow * child;

    ParentWindow() : Fl_Window(100, 100, 400, 300, "Parent"){
        Fl_Button * b = new Fl_Button(10, 10, 70, 20, "Make Child");
        b->callback(CallbackMakeChild, NULL);
        this->add(b);
        this->end();
        this->show();

        std::cout << "Parent XID: " << (void *)fl_xid(this) << '\n';
    }

    static void CallbackMakeChild(Fl_Widget * w, void * o){
        child = new ChildWindow();
        child->show();
    }
};

ChildWindow * ParentWindow::child = NULL;
```

with the main function of

```
int main(){
    ParentWindow parent;
    Fl::run();
}
```

When run, the above code should create a window with a button. When the button is pressed, a child window will be created and the X Window will be attempted to be created. Here is the console output:

```
Parent XID: 0x4400002
Child XID: 0x4400005
XWindow XID: 0xe03140
X_CreateWindow: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 0x4400005
X_ConfigureWindow: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 0x4600001
X_MapWindow: BadWindow (invalid Window parameter) 0x4600001
```

The child window and X Window by themselves behave fine:

```
int main(){
    ChildWindow child;
    Fl::run();
}
```

This code (creating two non-hierarchical windows) also fails:

```
int main(){
    ChildWindow child1; // This window works
    ChildWindow child2; // This causes similar errors as above
    Fl::run();
}
```

I have also tried various combinations of `fl_open_display` and `Fl_Window::make_current` without success.

*(All code, being in one file, compiles by running `./fltk-config --compile myprog.cpp`)*

The pattern here appears that X windows initialize fine for the first FLTK window, but do not for windows created after that. My guess is that it has something to do with how FLTK interfaces/initializes with XLib, but I have not been able to find specifics in the documentation.

Does anyone have an explanation/solution for why X Window initialization only works when using the first-created FLTK window as a parent?

Comment: Consider asking that on some [FLTK](http://www.fltk.org/newsgroups.php?gfltk.general+T) group

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I will do that. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You are mixing FLTK with low-level X11 API. This makes no sense. Why do you need `XOpenDisplay` `XCreateSimpleWindow` and all this?!

Comment: @n.m. Proprietary software that requires low-level interface. I tried using FLTK handles, but they did not work with said proprietary software, so I had to use something else.

Comment: It would be doable to break my GUIs into separate executables, but I wanted to see if I could solve the original problem first.

Comment: hmm XOpenDisplay makes no sense in any case, FLTK already has an open displa (fl_display), there's no need to open another one.

Comment: @n.m. Great suggestion!!! I got it to work by taking out the second open display call. I'll post an answer in a couple minutes. Thank you much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `XOpenDisplay` was being called twice. FLTK opens the display as part of the initialization process, and calling it again with initializing the X window messed up the system.

This was solved by removing the line that said `dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL)` and replacing references to `dis`, with the FLTK display located at `fl_display`.